# MS Project multiple entry dates with duration for single task

Tags: ms-project, project-planning

What is the best way to maintain the following hierarchy in Microsoft Project (.mpp) file?

Country will have multiple Jobs and each Job will have multiple of Phases and each Phase will have multiple Employees and then each Employee will have multiple EntryDates with Hours.

I want to track/show the %complete, remaining duration, task delay based these Employee EntryDates with Hours and Baseline Estimation.

Here is the sample data structure,

```
[
    {Country:{Name:"US",Jobs:[
        {Name:"Job 1",Phases:[
            {Name:"Phase 1",BaselineDuration:"90 days", BaselineStart:"2023-01-01", BaseLineFinish:"2023-03-30",Employees:[
                {Name:"John",EntryDates:[{DateEntered:"2023-12-01",Hours:6},{DateEntered:"2023-12-02",Hours:8},{DateEntered:"2023-12-05",Hours:9}]},
                {Name:"Rosy",EntryDates:[{DateEntered:"2023-11-04",Hours:2},{DateEntered:"2023-12-02",Hours:8},{DateEntered:"2023-10-16",Hours:9}]}]},
            {Name:"Phase 2",BaselineDuration:"90 days", BaselineStart:"2023-01-01", BaseLineFinish:"2023-03-30",Employees:[
                {Name:"Lucy",EntryDates:[{DateEntered:"2023-12-03",Hours:7},{DateEntered:"2023-12-01",Hours:6},{DateEntered:"2023-12-05",Hours:9}]},
                {Name:"Rosy",EntryDates:[{DateEntered:"2023-10-04",Hours:2},{DateEntered:"2023-11-02",Hours:8},{DateEntered:"2023-10-16",Hours:9}]}]}]},
        {Name:"Job 2",Phases:[
            {Name:"Phase 1",BaselineDuration:"90 days", BaselineStart:"2023-01-01", BaseLineFinish:"2023-03-30",Employees:[
                {Name:"John",EntryDates:[{DateEntered:"2023-09-01",Hours:6},{DateEntered:"2023-08-02",Hours:8},{DateEntered:"2023-11-05",Hours:9}]},
                {Name:"Rosy",EntryDates:[{DateEntered:"2023-07-04",Hours:2},{DateEntered:"2023-02-02",Hours:8},{DateEntered:"2023-05-16",Hours:9}]}]},
            {Name:"Phase 2",BaselineDuration:"90 days", BaselineStart:"2023-01-01", BaseLineFinish:"2023-03-30",Employees:[
                {Name:"Lucy",EntryDates:[{DateEntered:"2023-01-03",Hours:7},{DateEntered:"2023-02-01",Hours:6},{DateEntered:"2023-09-05",Hours:9}]},
                {Name:"Rosy",EntryDates:[{DateEntered:"2023-03-04",Hours:2},{DateEntered:"2023-06-02",Hours:8},{DateEntered:"2023-06-16",Hours:9}]}]}]}
        ]}}
]
```

Comment: As this question is not about programming, but rather how to use Microsoft Project, it belongs on the [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) site.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will ask on the [Project management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/)